# How can I put an else or catch block on a new line for PHP files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to to configure vscode formatter in this way, that an else or catch block in php will be on a new line?

instead of this formatting:

```
if($first){
    echo "Hello";
} else {
    echo "world";
}
```

it sholud be like this:

```
if($first)
{
    echo "Hello";
} 
else 
{
    echo "world";
}
```

Comment: Don't know about visual studio, but Sublime Text as [addons](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter/blob/master/PHP-Transformations.md).